# Mask and Check Validate input date by textbox in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi i get date in textbox in Ms-Access in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
to Check Validate input date by entered user, my code in LostFocus DateCutting TextBox:

```
On Local Error GoTo Baddates
myDate = DateCutting.Text
TextBox1.Text = FormatDateTime(myDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
Baddates:
MsgBox "Please Insert Correct Date! "
```

For example, i want prevent to enter 15 for month but i get my message "Please Insert Correct Date!" always so focus on next object.

Comment: You need an ```exit sub``` the msgbox always triggers otherwise.

Comment: Is the control bound to a date field? If yes, just set the `Format` property (properties window) to "yyyy/mm/dd" (without the quotes). The control itself won't allow invalid dates.

Comment: no it is only a textbox to get date

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot more - *inputmask, format,* and *code* - too much to post here.

Study my project [VBA.DateEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry) having full code.

Documentation including a demo application is published here:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html?preview=Eh7VEzgKeXU%3D)